# Displaying value from child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what is the `query` to display specific database, "nama" from database, but got all value in child, i used this code

```
dbResepNusantara.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){...
```

**Database structure**

[image: Database]

**value**

[image: value]

Comment: You need a single value, `Ikan Gurameh Bekaj` from `1` child or your all `nama` from all childs?

Answer (score 1):

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference ref= database.child("resepNusantara");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String value=data.child("nama").getValue().toString();
    Log.i("nama",value);

    }
  }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The above will give you value of child `nama`.

If you add a breakpoint, this line `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {` will give you all the keys and values under `resepNusantara`, since dataSnapshot is on that location.

If you only want it to give you only `nama` from `child(1)` then you have to be more specific of the location and do this:

```
DatabaseReference ref= database.child("resepNusantara").child("1").child("nama");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //dataSnapshot location is child("nama")
String value=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
Log.i("nama",value);

}
```